# Highcharts will not display anything in the div container with jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, highcharts

This is my first time using highcharts alongside with jade and the MEAN stack. I am able to get the chart to work on a jsfiddle, but it will not display anything inside of the div when running locally.

this is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eajnerrx/) I used jade-lang to convert the jade into html so I would be able to put it into jsfiddle.

```
<div id="chartcon" style="min-width: 310px; height:400px; margin 0 auto"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highchart.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(function() {
    $('#chartcon').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
                text: 'colum chart w/ neg values'
        },
        xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples','Oranges', 'Pears']
        },
        credits: {
                enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5,3,4]
        }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2,-2,-3]
        }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3,4,5]
        }]
                });
        });
```

I am trying to do this in a single jade file, which I have been thinking may be the problem (I can't find to much on using jade with highcharts so this leads me to think it may not be compatible?)

Comment: It should be compatible (at least I don't know any reason why it shouldn't). Do you have any errors in JS console when opening page with jade template? Is the above code exactly the same as the one you have in your page?

Comment: yes it is exactly what I have in my page. The only error I receive is missing space before text for line x of jade file.

Comment: I mean errors in javascript console. The only mistake in your code is `/code.highchart.com/` -> should be `highcharts`.